# What can we conclude for the spin configuration of the quarks inside the baryon?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, quarks, elementary-particles, baryons

If yes, is there any way to reconcile this findings with Pauli's exclusion principle?

Comment: what "if yes" ? The title question cannot be answered with a yes or a no.

Answer (score 1):

It has been reconciled through the use of the color charge, which also forms the basis of quantum chromodynamics, the unique theory of strong interactions which matches experimental results (particularly the phenomenology of three jet events).